# How to display a table from a polygon on Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, google-earth-pro

I have a polygon that I am working on in ArcMap 10.3. It has an attribute table with about 300 some columns. I am having trouble displaying the whole attribute table on Google Earth when I export the polygon layer to kml.

When I click on the polygon in Google Earth, only the last column of data will be displayed.

Any tips or suggestions on how get the whole table to be displayed?

The photo below shows how only only one column but all the row fields of the table are displayed

[image: This shows only one column and all the rows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KMLs do not support information the same way a shapefile does. KML and shapefile conversions work well enough to display geographical information.  Since KMLs do not have a full table structure behind them, you will find it lacking for converting large amounts of information. If you try and convert that KML back to a shapefile, all of that will transfer into a single field. If you were to make more fields in your KML, it will still all transfer back into one field.

Perhaps shed some light into what you're trying to accomplish and maybe someone has an alternative way!

Comment: Thanks for the response, Adam. My hope was that as a user navigated google earth and clicked on the polygon a table would pop up, where the user could scroll through the data. I am trying to display a table of historical forest fires located in each national forest. Ideally, I would display the fires as points, but unfortunately not all fires have coordinates included in their data set, so I did a many to one join to the forest polygon so that at least the fires without coordinates could be spatially referenced.

Comment: I was actually experimenting with this issue a few weeks back as a possible alternative to ArcGIS Online. I know you can code the KML to shapefile transfer so the fields go into their respective fields. Is there a specific reason why you are using a KML in Google Earth instead of just doing this in ArcMap? If you don't need to export a KML, you can accomplish your traditional table structure in Google My Maps. You can geocode your locations and doing so from excel or Google Sheets will create your typical columns. Only problem is you cannot export geocodes to Earth.

Comment: I work on a wildland fire crew and am hoping to show how many fires the crew has been on throughout the crew's history and on what national forest. Many of crew members aren't too familiar with ArcMap but seem to have Google Earth on their computers. My goal is to create a map that they could view and interact with.  Where they could click on the forest polygon and a table displaying all the fires would pop up. I thought about ESRI's ArcGIS Earth program, but I will have to spend more time becoming familiar it.

Comment: The problem with ArcGIS Earth is that it was just released and Google has over a decade head start on them. ESRI's aerials are generally a few years out of date in most areas and I don't think there is the option to show historical aerials. 

I would definitely suggest using Google My Maps then (it'll be stored in your Google Drive). You can import shapefiles directly. You can also geocode a table then if you have coordinates in it so your fields show up how you want them. Then here's the best part: no need for KML. You can share the map via link or webpage!

Comment: Thanks, Adam for walking through this with me. I'll take this approach and see what I can come with. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know how it works out!

Comment: Also look into Fusion Tables - a document type under Google Drive.